# R: Exception handling with try()

Tags: r, try-catch

I have a list of 15 files stored in an object `FILELIST`. The task is to read all the files from `FILELIST` from a particular directory and append one below other.

In below code, object called 'dataset' will have the final appended file. The issue I am facing is if one or more files present in `FILELIST` is not present in directory, I am getting an error as below. What I need is if 1 or more out of 15 files are not present in the directory, code should proceed appending rest of the files.

I have tried with `try` exception handling method, but still getting below error and the code doesn't process rest of the files.

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'PREDICTION_2016_Q4_Wk13.csv': No such file or directory

Code:

```
for (file in FILELIST) {
  try(    
    if (!exists("dataset")) {
      dataset <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep=",")
    }
    if (exists("dataset")) {
      temp_dataset <-read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep=",")
      dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
      rm(temp_dataset)
    },
    silent = T
  )
}
```

Comment: As all solutions below suggest, you should lose the `for` loop here, and you do not need the `try` call. Also, if your files contain some columns that are going to be interpreted as factors, expect slower execution than if you set `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use exception handling for this. Instead do something like this:

```
for (file in intersect(FILELIST, list.files())) {
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `file.exists` and `Filter` to reduce `FILELIST` to the ones that exist and then read each one and `rbind` them together at the end.

Note that this works both in the situation that `FILELIST` contains file names from the current directory and also works if the files are located elsewhere and path/filenames are specified in `FILELIST`.

No packages are used.

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(Filter(file.exists, FILELIST), read.csv))
```

**Update:**  Improved code.

Comment: "No packages are used" :-P

Answer (score 0):

Combination of the two other answers, using `readr` + `dplyr` for speed:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

# existing files
f <- intersect(FILELIST, list.files())

# or identically:
# f <- intersect(FILELIST, dir())
# f <- FILELIST[ file.exists(FILELIST) ]

# combine in a single dataset
d <- bind_rows(lapply(f, read_csv))
```